# How to rename a reference?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

In Writer, there exist an option to create references for futher "inserting". That's mean: select some word, then click Insert > Cross-reference. In the new window, select "Set reference" in the "Type" area, and give it some name, for example Reference1. Then click "Insert" button. The reference in successfully created.

[image]

But how I can rename it in the future? For example, from Reference1 to Reference5 (or something more meaningful)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation of LibreOffice, listed as a bug at https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43254.

However it is possible to rename the reference by unzipping the ODT file and editing `content.xml` with a text editor.  Search and replace all occurrences of `Reference1`.

Answer (score 3):

I have found an alternative solution using a LibreOffice Writer extension.

### Install the extension

Install the [Alternative Find & Replace for Writer (AltSearch)](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer) extension for Libre Office (compatible with version 3.3+). Download the extension then in Writer go to `Tools` > `Extension Manager` then click `Add` and select the file for the extension you downloaded.

The extension is accessible via `Edit` > `Alt. Find & Replace` or by clicking on this icon in the toolbar:

[image: Icon]

### Perform the replacement

Using the example in the original post, let's say we have *set* a cross-reference named `reference1` with the value `test` which we want to rename to `reference5`. Let's say we also have also *inserted* one or more cross-references in the document referring to the set cross-reference. Open the alternative find & replace and carry out the following steps:

In `Search for`:

- **Alternative 1:** type `[::ReferenceMark::]\\Reference1` in the box.
- **Alternative 2:** select `Cross-ref. marker (text)` from the `Extended` drop down menu and add `\\Reference1` manually to the search box).

In `Replace`:

- **Alternative 1:** type `\B{Reference5|\o}` in the box.
- **Alternative 2:** select `Insert marker+text for cross-reference` from the `Replace` drop down menu. In the box, replace `ref1` with `Reference5` and replace `text` with `\o`.
- **Note:** if you want to change the *value* of the set cross-reference at the same time, replace `\o` with the new value.

Click `replace all` to perform the replacement.

[image: Screenshot]

At this point, all we've done is change the *set* cross-reference. Any *inserted* cross-references in the document will now point to a set cross-reference which no longer exists, so we have to change those too. These steps assume that the inserted cross-references display the *value* of the set cross-reference (as opposed to e.g. the page number or some other attribute). See breakdown further below if you need to update other types of cross-references.

In `Search for`:

- **Alternative 1:** type `[::Reference::]\\Reference1` in the box.
- **Alternative 2:** select `Cross-reference (text)` from the `Extended` drop down menu and add `\\Reference1` manually to the search box).

In `Replace`:

- **Alternative 1:** type `\L{2,0,Reference5}` in the box.
- **Alternative 2:** select `Insert cross-reference to marker` from the `Replace` drop down menu. In the box, replace `0,0` with `2,0` and replace `ref1` with `Reference5`.

Click `replace all` to perform the replacement.

[image: Screenshot]

### Breakdown

In `[::ReferenceMark::]\\Reference1`:

- `[::ReferenceMark::]` means we are searching for a *set* cross-reference.
- `\\` means we want to find the reference by its *name*.
- `Reference1` is the name of the reference we are searching for.

In `\B{Reference5|\o}`:

- `\B` means we will replace the found reference with a new one.
- `Reference5` is the *name* for the new reference.
- `\o` means the *value* of the new reference will be the *value* of the old reference that was found.

In `[::Reference::]\\Reference1`:

- `[[:Reference:]]` means we are searching for an *inserted* cross-reference.
- `\\` means we want to find the reference by the *name* that it refers to.
- `Reference1` is the name of the reference that we are searching for.

In `\L{2,0,Reference5}`:

- `\L` means we will replace the *inserted* cross-reference with a new inserted cross-reference.
- `2` means that the new inserted-cross reference will be of type "reference" i.e. it will display the *value* of the set cross-reference.
- `0` means the type of the reference is a set cross-reference (as opposed to a numbered paragraph etc.).
- `Reference5` is the name that the new inserted cross-reference will refer to.

To do replacements of other types of cross-references (e.g. to page numbers) the `2` will need to be modified to one of the following (extracted from the [documentation](http://macrojtb.hys.cz/HelpAltSearch_en.html)):

> 0 - page number in Arabic numerals, 1 - chapter number, 2 - the
> reference text , 3 - above/below , 4 - page number using the numbering
> type defined in the page style, 5 - category and number of a caption,
> 6 - caption text, 7 - number of a sequence field (caption)

### Other uses

On a separate note, the extension provides all kinds of other useful functionality which is missing in the standard find and replace. For example you can replace all instances of a style with another style (this being the original reason I installed it), and almost anything else you can think of. Refer to the extension's [homepage](http://macrojtb.hys.cz/HelpAltSearch_en.html) for detailed (if somewhat hard to parse) instructions.